# Function "OnApplicationPause" works when the application starts. Android, unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When I launch my game in game editor or on the phone - it glitches for the 2-3 seconds and  calls the function `OnApplicationPause`. But when I close application/pause in editor it doesn't calls. That's bad for my project so how to fix it? There's function code :

```
void OnApplicationPause()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    SaveVariablesInClass();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("SV", JsonUtility.ToJson(save)); //saves special class
}

void SaveVariablesInClass()
{
    save.Bananas = bananas;
    save.GoldBananas = goldBananas;

    save.TwoBananasSpawnChance = twoBananasSpawnChance;
    save.HigherBananaLevelChance = higherBananaLevelChance;
    save.SimpleBananaStormChance = simpleBananaStormChance;

    save.GoldBananaChance = goldBananaChance;
    save.TwoGoldBananaChance = twoGoldBananaChance;

    save.offlineEfficiency = offlineEfficiency;
    save.offlineProductionTime = offlineProductionTime;

    save.goldCoefficient = goldCoefficient;

    save.BonusLevels = bonusLevels;
    save.GoldBonusLevels = goldBonusLevels;
    save.SimpleBonusLevelPrices = simpleBonusLevelPrices;
    save.GoldBonusLevelPrices = goldBonusLevelPrices;
    save.simpleMaxLevels = simpleMaxLevels;
    save.goldMaxLevels = goldMaxLevels;

    save.time = time.ToString();

    save.CurrentSimpleBonus1 = currentSimpleBonus1;
    save.LaunchedGame = launchedGame;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your code? Also please decide for one tag .. your code is either `c#` or `javascript` but probably not both. What do you mean by `it slows down a bit`? When you are launching the App how can it slow down? Also have a look at [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: did you try giving `OnApplicationPause` a `bool` parameter and skip if it is `false`?

Comment: I tried it now, but then I can't save my progress. 
Some time ago this did not happen.

Comment: Yes it should still be done if the bool value is `true`. What is `SaveVariablesInClass();` doing? just trying to see where the lag could be caused

Comment: Edited. Maybe I try to save too many information to PlayerPrefs?

Comment: I discovered that `OnApplicationPause()` also doesn't works in the real pause and the lag in the start of game depends on Rendering. Detail information : https://imgur.com/a/LSxmLX3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the bool parameter in the method. It should be `OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)`. OnApplicationPause is called on each GameObject after Awake. So your code should be:

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
       DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
       SaveVariablesInClass();
       PlayerPrefs.SetString("SV", JsonUtility.ToJson(save)); //saves special class
    }
}
```

The lag you show in comments is caused by rendering not script.

Comment: I tried it again and my method does not work anyway. Neither during a pause nor when leaving the game.

Comment: Thanks! It started working when I tested it on the Android device!

Comment: No problem. Also PlayerPrefs are not the best for saving all the game data. Data saved in PlayerPrefs is easy to change by a user and should be used mainly for things like game settings.